# Reshape JSON response in Powery Query

Tags: azure-data-factory, powerquery

I am trying to use Power Query to get data from an API. However, I think Power Query is having difficulty with the schema. I can't find the right steps in PowerQuery to make this a flat table containing all of the data. I'm using a Gen2 DataFlow within Microsoft Fabric (an extension of Azure Data Factory) and want to save the output to a flat LakeHouse table.

The JSON response I get:

```
{
   "Dimension1": {
      "TimeStamp1": "Fact 11",
      "TimeStamp2": "Fact 11"
   },
   "Dimension2": {
      "TimeStamp1": "Fact 21",
      "TimeStamp2": "Fact 22"
   }
}
```

The following code works perfectly in python/pandas to achieve what I want:

```
json_response = requests.get(request_string).json() #the response from above
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(json_response)
```

Output from `print(df.head(2)`:

```
             Dimension 1 | Dimension 2
TimeStamp1 | Fact11        Fact21
TimeStamp2 | Fact12        Fact22
```

When I pull this into Power Query, it interprets it as two records where the key is the Dimension and the value is a list of records, one for each TimeStamp/Fact pair. This makes sense, but I can't figure out what to do in PowerQuery to get it to wind up the way I want it.

The closest I have gotten is by converting to a Table. From here, I can expand the column that contains the lists, which gives me a column for every TimeStamp. This feels wrong for a few reasons:

1. This is not scalable if I have thousands of TimeStamps
2. PowerQuery explicitly names each column, making the mquery text long and unreadable
3. Somehow, I lose the Fact data when I do this, and all the results become null.

Another acceptable output would be:

```
TimeStamp | Dimension | Fact
------------------------------
TimeStamp1  Dimension1  Fact11
TimeStamp2  Dimension1  Fact12
TimeStamp1  Dimension2  Fact21
TimeStamp2  Dimension2  Fact22
```

Comment: did this work for you

Answer (score 1):

In PowerQuery, how about

```
let Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\temp2\a.json")),
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Record.ToList(Source), Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error) ,
#"AddFieldNames"=Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(#"Converted to Table")&{Record.FieldNames(Source)},{"Column1","Dimension"}),
ExpandList= List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column( #"AddFieldNames", "Column1"), each if _ is record then Record.FieldNames(_) else {}))),
Expand= Table.ExpandRecordColumn( #"AddFieldNames", "Column1", ExpandList,ExpandList),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Expand, {"Dimension"}, "Attribute", "Value")
in #"Unpivoted Other Columns"
```

[image]

OR

```
let Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\temp2\a.json")),
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Record.ToList(Source), Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error) ,
#"AddFieldNames"=Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(#"Converted to Table")&{Record.FieldNames(Source)},{"Column1","Dimension"}),
ExpandList= List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column( #"AddFieldNames", "Column1"), each if _ is record then Record.FieldNames(_) else {}))),
Expand= Table.ExpandRecordColumn( #"AddFieldNames", "Column1", ExpandList,ExpandList),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Expand, {"Dimension"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", List.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Other Columns"[Dimension]), "Dimension", "Value")
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

Comment: Did this work for you? If so, please toggle checkmark to mark as solved and consider upvoting with arrow